# Why are my Sagemaker Training jobs running slower than the same process on a notebook?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm instantiating a Sagemaker training job using a Pytorch estimator (sagemaker.pytorch.estimator). I have compared performance with the same training task, executed manually on a Sagemaker notebook of identical hardware ('ml.g4dn.8xlarge').

The job instantiated through the SDK (Pytorch estimator) runs at approximately 15s/it. This is significantly slower than the same task running on a notebook, which achieves 1.6s/it.

Are training jobs executed through the Sagemaker SDK expected to be so much slower?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, this also depends on your setup. What is the size of your training data and where is it located? There are vanilla and distributed training jobs as well, so this configuration also matters. Training Jobs can be tuned with either model/data parallel as well as the data source you are using.

Different Data Sources With SageMaker Training Jobs: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/choose-the-best-data-source-for-your-amazon-sagemaker-training-job/

Comment: Both jobs are identical, as far as I can see, so both datasets are identical. On the notebook job I manually copy the dataset to a local folder. On the sagemaker execturo instantiation I nominate 'File' mode as the input_mode.